# Spring Data Models - Abstract Base Classes With Lombok?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a design question around models in Spring Data (and in my specific case Spring Data Mongo).

My requirements:

- I want to enforce that all aggregate roots use a String as the datatype for ID.
- I want to force IDs that are empty string or whitespace to be marshalled to null (so mongo generates a key for those)
- I want to eventually add standard auditing attributes for each aggregate root.
- I want to use Lombok for the models to reduce boilerplate.

I have seen several examples where an abstract base class is used:

```java
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class PersistentDocument implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    public void setId(String id) {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(getId())) {
            this.id = null;
        } else {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
    public String getId() {
        this.id;
    }
    .
    .
    auditing fields...etc.
}
```

Descendant:

```java
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class UnitOfMeasure extends PersistentDocument {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

There are two problems:

- This relies on the experimentation "SuperBuilder"
- There is a need to manually add a constructor to include the super's fields which negates some of the benefits of Lombok.

As an alternative, I started toying with using an interface to enforce datatype standards:

```java
public interface PersistentDocument extends Serializable {

    void setId(String id);
    public String getId();

    .
    . Setters/Getters for audit fields
}
```

This is a little better, but each descendant document is on the hook to correctly implement the logic to convert whitespace to null and to annotate the audit fields.

I am really interested to see what others are doing?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to go ahead and answer my own question:

In order to take advantage of Lombok for handling the boilerplate code and to also enforce that all of the aggregate roots follow the same convention for the ID and auditing attributes:

I decided to use the interface:

```java
@Document
public interface PersistentDocument extends Serializable {

    void setId(String id);
    String getId();

    @CreatedDate
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    void setCreatedTimestamp(LocalDateTime timestamp);
    LocalDateTime getCreatedTimestamp();

    @LastModifiedDate
    void setLastModifiedTimestamp(LocalDateTime timestamp);
    LocalDateTime getLastModifiedTimestamp();

    @Version
    void setVersion(Long version);
    Long getVersion();
}
```

A really nice, but subtle, thing about the interface is that the spring data annotations can be applied on the interface rather than the models. This does not completely remove annotations from the models (you still need to annotation your model fields with indexes for example).

The model objects just define properties and leverage Lombok:

```java
@Data
@Builder
public class UnitOfMeasure implements PersistentDocument {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    //Audit Columns
    private LocalDateTime createdTimestamp;
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedTimestamp;
    private Long version;
}
```

To address sanitation of the empty string/whitespace persistent IDs:

I was able to extend the SimpleMongoRepository with my own implementation:

```java
public class PersistentDocumentMongoRepository<T extends PersistentDocument> extends SimpleMongoRepository <T, String> {

    public PersistentDocumentMongoRepository(MongoEntityInformation<T, String> metadata, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        sanitizeId(entity);
        return super.save(entity);
    }


    @Override
    public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {

        Assert.notNull(entities, "The given Iterable of entities not be null!");
        Streamable.of(entities).stream().forEach(this::sanitizeId);
        return super.saveAll(entities);
    }


    @Override
    public <S extends T> S insert(S entity) {
        sanitizeId(entity);
        return super.insert(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> List<S> insert(Iterable<S> entities) {
        Assert.notNull(entities, "The given Iterable of entities not be null!");
        Streamable.of(entities).stream().forEach(this::sanitizeId);
        return super.insert(entities);
    }

    private void sanitizeId(T entity) {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(entity.getId())) {
            entity.setId(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally telling Spring Data to use the custom repository implementation with :

```java
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryBaseClass=PersistentDocumentMongoRepository.class)
```

I hope this helps others and I really would like to see how others are addressing similar problems.